# Using phoenix to save a dataframe on Hbase

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

As the title says, I want to save my DataFrame with phoenix.
I have a spark code in scala that I run on intellij IDEA.
It is quite simple :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.phoenix.spark._

object MainTest extends App {
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse")
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("spark-to-hbase")
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext
  val sqlC = sparkSession.sqlContext
  import sqlC.implicits._

  val myRdd = sc.parallelize(List(("a",1), ("b", 2)))
  myRdd.collect.foreach(println)
  val myDf = myRdd.toDF("column1", "column2")
  myDf.show()
  myDf.saveToPhoenix("MY_TABLE", zkUrl = Some("localhost:16000"))
}
```

I also have a HBase database runing on the same pc on the port 16000.
The problem is that the line

```
myDf.saveToPhoenix("MY_TABLE", zkUrl = Some("localhost:16000"))
```

throw this exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/types/DataType    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$getFieldArray$2.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$getFieldArray$2.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:72)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions.getFieldArray(DataFrameFunctions.scala:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions.saveToPhoenix(DataFrameFunctions.scala:35)
>     at MainTest$.delayedEndpoint$MainTest$1(MainTest.scala:23)  at
>   MainTest$delayedInit$body.apply(MainTest.scala:8)     at
>   scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)    at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
>     at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)    at
>   scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)   at
>   scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
>     at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)   at
>   MainTest$.main(MainTest.scala:8)  at MainTest.main(MainTest.scala)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.types.DataType    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 33 more

From what I understand, it seems that java can't find some class.
What can I do ?

My SBT :

```
name := "spark-to-hbase"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-core" % "4.11.0-HBase-1.3",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-spark" % "4.11.0-HBase-1.3"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `saveToPhoenix` takes RDDs.  For dataframes, use `save` (see this [doc](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html) for more details):

```
myDf.save("org.apache.phoenix.spark", SaveMode.Overwrite,
  Map("MY_TABLE" -> "OUTPUT_TABLE", "zkUrl" -> "localhost:16000"))
```

Comment: My IDEA tells me that it cannot resolve the save method. I have imported phoenix-spark and phoenix-core 4.11. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.
As the exception says, my compiler isn't able to find the class HBaseConfiguration.
HBaseConfiguration is used inside org.apache.hadoop.hbase library and so is needed to compile.
I noticed that the HBaseConfiguration class wasn't present in the org.apache.hadoop library as I thought.
For the hbase 1.3.1 version installed on my PC computer, I managed to find this class in the hbase-common-1.3.1 jar located in my HBASE_HOME/lib folder.

Then I include this dependency in my built.SBT :

```
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.3.1"
```

And the Exception was gone.